# Showing only some part of the list on the Grid Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

Here is an exemplary code piece:

**Model.cs**

```
public class Datas
{
    public int Region;
    public int Frequency;
    public int Amplitude;
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public Datas Data1;

public MainViewModel()
{
    DataList = new ObservableCollection<Datas>();   
    GetDatas();
}

public ObservableCollection<Datas> DataList { get; set; }

public void GetDatas()
{
    ...
    ...

    var command = new SqlCommand($"Select [Region], [Frequency], [Amplitude].. WHERE REGION = '{SelectedRegion}..");
    var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        var Data1 = new Datas();
        Data1.Region = dataReader["Region"];
        Data1.Frequency = dataReader["Frequency"];
        Data1.Amplitude = dataReader["Amplitude"];

        DataList.Add(Data1);
    }

    connection.close();
}
```

(I tried to use DevExpressMVVM tools.)

**MainView.xaml**

```
<dxg:GridControl ItemsSource = "{Binding DataList} ...../>
```

Now; I can see the table on the window with Region, Frequency, and Amplitude columns and their values.
**But I want only to show the 2 columns; maybe like Frequency and Amplitude.**

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/6094/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/grid-view-data-layout/columns-and-card-fields/create-columns-and-bind-them-to-data-properties

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In XAML or in code you can set the column visibility to hidden.
If you give a name to your datagrid you can access his properties.

```
<dxg:GridControl Name="myDatagrid" ItemsSource = "{Binding DataList} ...../>
```

then in code :

```
myDataGrid.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to do this directly on the xaml code? There is a visibility property but how to choose the column number in xaml?

Comment: if you declared the columns in XAML : <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Visibility="Hidden"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>